# Gerando arquivo zip recebendo de file input

Tags: php, arquivo-zip, yii2

Tenho que gerar o zip através de um upload via file input, receber compactar se nao for compactado e deixar pronto para download. Está funcionando, o problema é que se o arquivo enviado for zip ele compacta novamente e gera outro zip, se for .pdf ele compacta e faz upload do .pdf também. Por que está duplicando o arquivo zip? Gostaria de resolver este problema.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if ($insert) {
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Recife');

            $this->data = date('d/m/Y');
            $this->hora = date('H:i');
            $this->dir = str_replace('', '', $this->nome . $_FILES['doc1']['name']);
            $zip = new \ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open('../documentos/' . $this->dir . '.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

                foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
                    if ($file['name']) {
                        $zip->addFile($file['tmp_name'], $file['name']);
                    }
                }

                $zip->close();
                $nome = $this->dir;

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc1']['tmp_name'], '../documentos/' . $nome);
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Documentos registrados com sucesso.");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom, aparentemente no código você cria o arquivo Zip e adiciona todos os arquivos do upload sem verificar o mimetype, então mesmo já sendo um Zip ele adicionará. Faça uma verificação do mime para saber se já é Zip ou não.

Comment: Mas Anderson, por que ele está movendo dois para o diretorio ../documentos?

Comment: Quanto ao conteudo tudo bem, o problema é que ele está enviando dois arquivos zips para o diretorio. Se atachar  um arquivo exemplo1.zip ele enviara exemplo1.zip e outro exemplo1.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que você criou o objeto *ZipArchive* e deu um nome à ele, esse arquivo foi criado no disco.

Ao final você invoca a função `move_uploaded_file()` que vai pegar o arquivo original e copiar também pra mesma pasta.

Ou seja, você não precisa desta linha:

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc1']['tmp_name'], '../documentos/' . $nome);
```

Tente comentá-la e teste a rotina outra vez.

Comment: Ei, Anderson deu certo. Valeu. Ele tava movendo realmente o conteudo que seria, o que o codigo gerou e o do file input. Vlw. galera. vlw anderson.